# Commutation relation for deviation of two hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, notation, commutator

On page 35, right after equation 1.4.60, Sakurai says that the commutator $$[\bigtriangleup A, \bigtriangleup B] = [A,B]$$

where $\bigtriangleup A = A - \langle A \rangle$, and $A$ is a hermitian operator.

I have worked out $[\bigtriangleup A, \bigtriangleup B]$ explicitly ($[x,y]=xy -yx$) but I cannot get that. I get

$$
[A,B] - [A,\langle B \rangle] -[\langle A \rangle,B] + [\langle A \rangle,\langle B \rangle]
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle A \rangle= \langle\psi |A|\psi\rangle$ (or more generally $\mathrm{Tr}(A\rho)$) is just a number , hence it commutes with everything. Since you want to subtract it from $A$ you actually have to think of it as $$\langle A \rangle\mathbb 1$$

which makes it even clearer that it commutes with $A$ and $B$, and same for $\langle B \rangle$.

Comment: unless I misunderstood the question

Comment: brilliant! very clear thank you :)
cheers!

Comment: could you take a look at a very related question of mine? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/546860/anti-commutator-of-deviation-operators-is-hermitian